# How to reduce noise on a warm air duct?

Tags: central-heating, sound-deadening

My heatings system is based on 80mm inox tubes. The air is warmed at a central location and distributed through these ducts.t

The issue is that the air pump is a bit noisy. This noise is transported through the tubes and heard in the rooms.

**Can I do something on the tubes to attenuate the noise propagation?**

Answer (score 2):

There are sound baffles that can be installed in your duct system.

Here’s a link that explains how they work: https://soundproofpanda.com/soundproof-air-vents/